# texreg: How to save space in htmlreg-regression tables?

Tags: r, regression, texreg

Is there a way to reduce the vertical size of a htmlreg-table? I have severeal modells with about 10 or more IV. So atm I need an entire page to present my regressions results. I would like to save some lines by reporting SD or SE (in parenthesis) inline (next to) the coefficients. Straightforward way is creating output-tables in latex by hand. Is there an easy solution (more elegant way)?

```
library(texreg)

alligator = data.frame(
  lnLength = c(3.87, 3.61, 4.33, 3.43, 3.81, 3.83, 3.46, 3.76,
               3.50, 3.58, 4.19, 3.78, 3.71, 3.73, 3.78),
  lnWeight = c(4.87, 3.93, 6.46, 3.33, 4.38, 4.70, 3.50, 4.50,
               3.58, 3.64, 5.90, 4.43, 4.38, 4.42, 4.25)
)

alli.mod = lm(lnWeight ~ lnLength, data = alligator)

htmlreg(list(alli.mod),
        file="MWE_regression.html", 
        caption="MWE Regression", 
        caption.above = TRUE,
        include.rs=TRUE, 
        include.adjrs = FALSE,
        digits=3,
        stars=c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1)
)
```

[image]

Thanks :)

**Update** The amazing, simple and elegant solution is using the stargazer-package. Quite new: http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/01/stargazer-package-for-beautiful-latex-tables-from-r-statistical-models-output/ this package can export wonderful latex-tables, much much better than the texreg.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd still like to accomplish this with `texreg` and its `htmlreg` function, just use the argument `single.row = TRUE`. Here is your full example:

```
library(texreg)

alligator = data.frame(
  lnLength = c(3.87, 3.61, 4.33, 3.43, 3.81, 3.83, 3.46, 3.76,
               3.50, 3.58, 4.19, 3.78, 3.71, 3.73, 3.78),
  lnWeight = c(4.87, 3.93, 6.46, 3.33, 4.38, 4.70, 3.50, 4.50,
               3.58, 3.64, 5.90, 4.43, 4.38, 4.42, 4.25)
)

alli.mod = lm(lnWeight ~ lnLength, data = alligator)

htmlreg(list(alli.mod),
        single.row = TRUE, 
        file="MWE_regression.html", 
        caption="MWE Regression", 
        caption.above = TRUE,
        include.rs=TRUE, 
        include.adjrs = FALSE,
        digits=3,
        stars=c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1)
)
```

Your original result is on the left, the new output on the right:

[image][image]

Use the `texreg` function instead of `htmlreg` if you are interested in LaTeX output rather than HTML, as mentioned in your additional comment.

**Edit**: The HTML output now looks a bit nicer with more recent versions of `texreg`.